# Python pandas: Setting row values in Pandas using data of that column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a fairly new and need some help with a small task I'm stuck with.

Basically I have a DataFrame with just one value in the first row and I want to fill out the rest of that empty column with data derived from the cell above.

Let's say that I start with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = range(100))
vol = 1.34
df.ix[0,'A'] = vol
```

And I want to have every row of column A (expect for the first one) = previous row + a random number

I've tried using shift but couldn't get the desired result:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].shift(1) + np.random.normal(0)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also just do it like this, which takes advantage of vectorization:

```
t = np.random.normal(size=100)
t[0] = vol
df = pd.DataFrame(t.cumsum())
```

Comment: Thanks for that - Is there a way to follow a similar way of using vectors if the calculation is for example: cell = previous cell * ln(random), i.e. where the cumsum can't be used?

Comment: cumprod? also, if the above answers your question, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
for i in xrange(1, len(df.index)):
    df.ix[i, 'A'] = df.ix[i - 1, 'A'] + np.random.normal(0)
```